# Cauchy-Schwarz inequality for Bochner spaces

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

Let $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mu)$ be a measure space, $(X, \Vert \cdot \Vert_X)$ be a Banach space, and let $(L^p(\Omega, X), \Vert \cdot \Vert_p)$, for $p \in \mathbb{N}$ be the Bochner space of measurable functions $u \colon \Omega \to X$ with finite norm

$$
\Vert u \Vert_{L^p(\Omega, X)}^p = \int_\Omega \Vert u(\omega) \Vert_X^p d\mu(\omega).
$$

One would hope that the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality holds for these spaces. Is this true for generic $X$ and $\mu$? Is there a reference where the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality is treated for these spaces, as opposed to the usual case $B=\mathbb{R}$ case

Comment: Do you perhaps mean Holder's Inequality? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H%C3%B6lder%27s_inequality Cauchy-Schwarz only applies when $p=2$ and you have an inner product structure.

Comment: Well, I do need Cauchy-Schwarz, but Hölder would be even better of course. Do you have such reference for the Hölder inequality?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Holder’s inequality very generally states that for every measurable function $f,g:\Omega\to [0,\infty]$, we have for every $1\leq p\leq\infty$ that
\begin{align}
\int_{\Omega}fg\,d\mu\leq \|f\|_{p}\|g\|_q,
\end{align}
where we allow the RHS to be infinite (and $q$ is the Holder conjugate). Using this carefully gives all sorts of corollaries.

Now, suppose you have three Banach spaces $X,Y,Z$ and a bounded bilinear map $\beta:X\times Y\to Z$. Rather than writing $\beta(x,y)$, let us write $x\cdot_{\beta} y$ (to remind us that $\beta$ is a ‘product’). Now, for any two (measurable) maps $u:\Omega\to X$ and $v:\Omega\to Y$, we can define the pointwise $\beta$-product map $u\cdot_{\beta} v:\Omega\to Z$. At each point, we have the estimate
\begin{align}
\|u(\omega)\cdot_{\beta} v(\omega)\|&\leq\|\beta\|\cdot \|u(\omega)\|\cdot\|v(\omega)\|.
\end{align}
So, taking $f(\omega)=\|u(\omega)\|$ and $g(\omega)=\|v(\omega)\|$ respectively, we have by Holder’s inequality that
\begin{align}
\int_{\Omega}\|u(\omega)\cdot_{\beta}v(\omega)\|\,d\mu(\omega)&\leq\|\beta\|\int_{\Omega}\|u(\omega)\|\cdot\|v(\omega)\|\,d\mu(\omega)\leq\|\beta\|\cdot\|u\|_{L^p(\Omega,X)}\cdot\|v\|_{L^q(\Omega,Y)}.
\end{align}
So, in short,
\begin{align}
\|u\cdot_{\beta}v\|_{L^1(\Omega,Z)}&\leq\|\beta\|\cdot\|u\|_{L^p(\Omega,X)}\cdot\|v\|_{L^q(\Omega,Y)},
\end{align}
which is exactly the usual Holder’s inequality we expect. In fact, taking $X=Y=Z=\Bbb{C}$, and $\beta$ the usual multiplication of complex numbers, we have $\|\beta\|=1$, so we get the usual complex-valued Holder’s inequality. Next, if $X$ is a Hilbert space, then taking $Y=X$ and $Z=\Bbb{C}$, you can let $\beta=\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle_X$ be the inner-product on $X$, and you get the integral version of Cauchy-Schwarz for Hilbert-space valued functions. There are lots of other types of bilinear pairings one might consider, for example:

- let $X=\Bbb{C}$ and $Z=Y$, and $\beta:\Bbb{C}\times Y\to Y$ the usual scalar multiplication (a very natural thing to consider).
- $X=\text{Hom}(Y,Z)$ and $\beta$ the bilinear evaluation map of operators on vectors. A very important special case is when $Z=\Bbb{C}$, in which case $\beta$ is the duality pairing $Y^*\times Y\to\Bbb{C}$ (typical cases include $Y=L^r(\Omega,\Bbb{C})$ or some Sobolev space (assuming $\Omega$ is open in $\Bbb{R}^n$, with say nice boundary etc), or whatever other function space of interest). The case of a Hilbert space (which I described above) is a special case of this once we use Riesz-representation to identify the Hilbert space with its dual using the inner product.
- take $X,Y,Z$ to be certain spaces of operators, and $\beta$ to be composition of operators.

These $\beta$’s all have $\|\beta\|\leq 1$, so you don’t even notice anything different from the usual Holder’s inequality. There are of course lots of other types of $\beta$’s to consider.

Comment: Thanks. Can $X=Y=Z=C(D)$, the space of continuous function on a compact $D$, or  $X=Y=Z=L^2(D)$, for instance?

Comment: As long as you have a $\beta$ in mind, sure.

Comment: I guess what escapes me is what is the natural $\beta$ for the case $C(D)$, which I typically assume being endowed with the supremum norm. I would really want to use just the point wise product for $C(D)$, and similarly for $L^2(D)$.

Comment: Ok, sure, for $C(D)$ with $D$ a compact topological space, equipped with supremum norm, you can consider the pointwise product. However for $L^2(D)$ ($D$ any measure space), the pointwise product lands you in $L^1(D)$ (by the usual Cauchy-Schwarz:) so you should take $X=Y=L^2(D),Z=L^1(D)$. For both these cases, $\|\beta\|\leq 1$.

Comment: That's fantastic, thank you!

Comment: And by a similar note, due to Holder’s inequality, you can take $X=L^r(D),Y=L^{r’}(D), Z=L^1(D)$ ($r,r’\in [1,\infty]$ Holder-conjugate exponents).

Comment: One last thing if I may: it seems I could also take for $\beta$ the standard inner product in $L^2(D)$ and take $Z=\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: yes, I already mentioned that right before my bullet points (and again in the second bullet point). In fact all the discussion in the comments is a special case of the bullet points lol